# pytest fixture scope for both session and class setup/teardown

Tags: pytest, fixtures

I know this is an old issue and thousands of people answered similar questions, but still I didn't get it...
What should I do to use setup/teardown for the whole test session as well as each test class?

For instance, I have the following test file structure:

- common_setup.py
- test_suite_1.py
- test_suite_2.py

And the files are like:

```
# common_setup.py
import logging
import pytest
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")

def set_session_data():
    # Setup
    logging.info("In session setup")

    # Teardown
    yield
    logging.info("In session teardown")
```

```
# test_suite_1.py
import logging
import pytest
import common_setup

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def set_data():
    # Setup
    logging.info("In test suite 1 setup")

    # Teardown
    yield
    logging.info("In test suite 1 teardown")

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("set_data")
class TestClass:
    def test_case_1():
        logging.info("In test suite 1, test case 1")


    def test_case_2():
        logging.info("In test suite 1, test case 2")
```

```
# test_suite_2.py
import logging
import pytest
import common_setup

@pytest.fixtures(scope="class")
def set_data():
    # Setup
    logging.info("In test suite 2 setup")

    # Teardown
    yield
    logging.info("In test suite 2 teardown")

@pytest.mark.usefixture("set_data")
class TestClass:
    def test_case_1():
        logging.info("In test suite 2, test case 1")


    def test_case_2():
        logging.info("In test suite 2, test case 2")
```

I would expect that the content in the session setup/teardown ("common_setup.py") should be executed per session and each test suite has it's own specific setup/teardown as well.

So far I have the log below, which means the session scoped method is not called. I know I didn't use it, but I cannot simply add it to usefixtures like @pytest.mark.usefixture("set_data", "set_session_data")

```
2022-11-28 15:16:25 INFO In test suite 1 setup
2022-11-28 15:16:25 INFO In test suite 1, test case 1
2022-11-28 15:16:25 INFO In test suite 1, test case 2
2022-11-28 15:16:25 INFO In test suite 1 teardown
2022-11-28 15:16:25 INFO In test suite 2 setup
2022-11-28 15:16:25 INFO In test suite 2, test case 1
2022-11-28 15:16:25 INFO In test suite 2, test case 2
2022-11-28 15:16:25 INFO In test suite 2 teardown
```

Any discussion is appriciated.
Thanks!

Tried with different options and the code above is already the furthest I could go...
The expected execution should be:

1. session setup (currently missing)
2. suite 1 setup
3. suite 1 case 1
4. suite 1 case 2
5. suite 1 teardown
6. suite 2 setup
7. suite 2 case 1
8. suite 2 case 2
9. suite 2 teardown
10. session teardown (currently missing)

Comment: Just add `autouse=True` to your session scoped fixture.

Comment: This leads me to [link](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/special.html) where literally answered everything for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MrBean Bremen
This comment directed me to this page which literally gives the whole answer: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/special.html

Not only I should place `autouse=True`, I also should rename the common_setup.py file to conftest.py, and it doesn't need to be imported.

So, overall, the things should be like:

- common_setup.py -> conftest.py
- test_suite_1.py
- test_suite_2.py

And the files are like:

```
# conftest.py
import logging
import pytest
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouser=True)

def set_session_data():
    # Setup
    logging.info("In session setup")

    # Teardown
    yield
    logging.info("In session teardown")
```

```
# test_suite_1.py
import logging
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def set_data():
    # Setup
    logging.info("In test suite 1 setup")

    # Teardown
    yield
    logging.info("In test suite 1 teardown")

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("set_data")
class TestClass:
    def test_case_1():
        logging.info("In test suite 1, test case 1")


    def test_case_2():
        logging.info("In test suite 1, test case 2")
```

```
# test_suite_2.py
import logging
import pytest

@pytest.fixtures(scope="class")
def set_data():
    # Setup
    logging.info("In test suite 2 setup")

    # Teardown
    yield
    logging.info("In test suite 2 teardown")

@pytest.mark.usefixture("set_data")
class TestClass:
    def test_case_1():
        logging.info("In test suite 2, test case 1")


    def test_case_2():
        logging.info("In test suite 2, test case 2")
```

And the log:

```
2022-11-28 16:28:59 INFO In test session setup
2022-11-28 16:28:59 INFO In test suite 1 setup
2022-11-28 16:28:59 INFO In test suite 1, test case 1
2022-11-28 16:28:59 INFO In test suite 1, test case 2
2022-11-28 16:28:59 INFO In test suite 1 teardown
2022-11-28 16:28:59 INFO In test suite 2 setup
2022-11-28 16:28:59 INFO In test suite 2, test case 1
2022-11-28 16:28:59 INFO In test suite 2, test case 2
2022-11-28 16:28:59 INFO In test suite 2 teardown
2022-11-28 16:28:59 INFO In test session teardown
```